# Proper Chef way to use Poise installed Python/Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, chef-infra

We are trying to use Poise to manage runtimes for [Python](https://github.com/poise/poise-python) and [Ruby](https://github.com/poise/poise-ruby) on our Centos7 servers. From my understanding this works with other recipes, but I can't figure out what the "right" way is to link the binaries to the standard bin locations (/usr/bin/, etc.). So far I have been unable to find a way to do this as part of the standard process - only by digging around to figure out where they were installed and then adding those links as a separate step later in the recipe - it seems like a major hack.

In other words, adding the following in a recipe that has some scripts that get copied to the server that require Python 3 looks like it installs Python 3:

```
python_runtime '3'
```

But the scripts (which cannot be changed) will never know that Python 3 exists.

Everything obviously works fine if I just do an install of Python3 using yum - which poise actually appears to do as well for Centos.

I am relatively new to Chef, but I have checked with our other devops team members and done a lot of searching and we couldn't figure out how this is officially supposed to be done. We aren't looking for more hacks as we can obviously do that, but what is the "Chef" way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately just linking the binaries wouldn't really help you much since by default on CentOS it will use the SCL packages which require some special environment variables to operate. If you want it to use the "normal" system you can do this:

```
python_runtime '3' do
  provider :system
end
```

However that will probably fail because there is no EL7 distro package for Python 3. If you want to continue using SCL packages but have them look like normal binaries, maybe try something like this:

```
file '/usr/local/bin/python' do # or .../python3 if you prefer
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '755'
  content "#!/bin/sh\nexec scl enable rh-python35 -- python3 \"$@\""
end
```

Or something like that. That still hardwires the fact that it is SCL under the hood and which SCL package is being used, which is not lovely, but the fully generic form (while doable) is a lot more complex.

Comment: Another option would be to use the IUS packages for Python, however IUS does not ship Ruby so you would have similar problems there with either using SCL or being stuck with the 2.0 distro package.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid it might be something like this, but this looks like a reasonable direction to go. For now I have just used a hacky feeling way of yum installing Python3 and setuptools, and then easy_installing pip to then install other necessary libs. Then of course everything is linked as expected, but it just isn't pretty.

Comment: If you do it all inside Chef, my code takes care of it for you :)